# Trying to adapt an Elo-ranking system for an asymetric multiplayer game

Tags: probability, statistics

My friends and I have used an [Elo-Ranking system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) to track our relative strength in the social deduction game "Secret Hitler". So far, the formula we used was a very basic adaptation of the original Elo-formula that uses a lot of assumptions and thus gives unfair results.
First, I will describe the relevant features of the game to those unfamiliar with it. Second, I will show our old formula and describe its shortcomings. Third and last, I will show the draft for our new formula. I will outline some potential problems with it that we have noticed and ask for your help in spotting any that we have overlooked.

---

The game is played with 5 to 10 people, seperated into 2 teams. The teams are of unequal, but predetermined size. (An 8-player game will always have teams of 3 vs 5 for example.) The smaller team ("red") has a smaller chance of winning than the larger team ("blue"). (In our data it's ~40%/60%.) We record wins (1) and losses (0) for each player and can infer the team they were on from that (3 wins and 5 losses in a game must mean team red won).

---

Old formula:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIxrP.png

- $E_n$ is your new Elo.
- $E_a$ is your old Elo.
- $k$ is a constant that is the max. delta between $E_n$ and $E_a$ per game.
- $Er$ is your personal result (1 or 0, draws are impossible in this game).
- $E_G$ is the opposite team's average Elo.
- $E_T$ is your own team's average Elo (including your personal Elo).
- $S$ is the stepsize. (A value of 40 means that if your Elo is 40 points higher than the opponent's it means that your expected value is one order of magnitude higher than your opponents.)

This makes a lot of assumptions, here are a few:

- Your likelihood of being on either team matches the theoretical distribution.
- You are just as good at playing on team red than you are at playing on team blue.

We also combine your own Elo and the overall team average with a 50/50 distribution, without considering cases like a pro playing with a team of noobs, where the pro's actions are more responsible for overall team performance (in our experience).

---

To eliminate some of these shortcomings, here is our new formula: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXHUQ.png 
(I am sorry for the links, this is my first question.)

- $F$ is the general winrate of the team you were on (red or blue).
- $A_E$ is your own contribution to the outcome relative to the rest of your team.
- $A_T$ is your teams contribution to the outcome relative to you.

All of these values are extracted from the raw results with some very inefficient and 'hacky' excel-code, but that is the topic of another post in another forum.
Some thoughts on the new formula: For some of these values, we can go two different routes, the comparative and the personal. For your faction's winrate for example we can either use the overall average (about 40/60) or take your own results into consideration: Maybe you are really good at playing on team red, bringing your average closer to 50/50. Shouldn't you then be rewarded for showing personal progress when you "unexpectedly" win a blue-team game? The latter has two drawbacks: While it gives you an Elo that more accurately tracks your personal progress, comparing these values between players is not fair. It also means that you need to have played a large number of games for your own values to become statistically relevant. In general, we 'officially' give players a ranking after their 10th game and gradually fade out the overall averages from the first to the 10th game, but that value was chosen arbitrarily without being rooted in data.
Our current solution is to calculate two Elo values for each player: A personal Elo that is a (weak) indicator of potential and a comparable Elo that determines the ranking. Something that we are not able to consider at all, due to the too-small number of games played in total, is whether a player is better at playing games of a certain size, i.e. 7-player games.

---

Have we overlooked something in our calculation, maybe another asymetry in the game that we are not aware of? Have we made a mistake in transfering our thoughts to a formula? Do you have a good idea how to incorporate some of our considerations that have not been implemented yet?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site. Please don’t rely on images to state your question; see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121.

Comment: @joriki Thank you for the link. I tried to get the formatting to work, but wasn't able to. Inline images would have been the second best option, but they are not available to new users, sorry.
I also know that direct, non-discussion questions are prefered here, but I didn't know where else to post this question. If someone has an alternative forum I'm happy to move the question there.